# MVC model validation depending on whether form is populated or not

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a viewmodel which consists of three models which are all displayed on the screen as one single form.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public PersonVM person { get; set; }
    public DepartmentVM department { get; set; }
    public EmploymentVM employment { get; set; }
}
```

When users fill in the form, they can fill one model details (example:- Person) and leave the other models details empty.

How do I implement model validation in my action method for all three models. I want to do model validation only if the model is populated (not null) for each of them.

How do I implement model validation depending on whether the individual model is populated or not ?

Comment: Are there 3 separate forms?

Comment: No. I am using only one form which displays all 3 models in different sections.

Comment: ok - you might want to change the text that says ' for all three forms' then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement `IValidatableObject` on your models

```
public class ViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public PersonVM person { get; set; }
    public DepartmentVM department { get; set; }
    public EmploymentVM employment { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // Add custom logic to validate each object
    }
}
```

If you add `IValidatableObject` to each of your form VMs then you could then call each of them from the `ViewModel` class

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a custom model validation. You can create a custom action filter by inheriting from `ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter`.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters